# dedicated rpd server unable to resolve domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have a rented dedicated Windows 2008R2 server. I use it for a remote development workstation.

I've been having a lot of issues using IE, firefox, and Chrome. It is saying that it could not find the site when I try browsing. This doesn't happen all the time, probably 50% of the time. I've tested all 3 and I'm having the same issue on of them. It's various sites also, such as gmail and google. The site will work one minute and not the next.

I was read that I should do an NSLOOKUP but I'm not familiar with what it the results are suppose to tell me:

```
C:\Users\tempuser>NSLOOKUP
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I am able to connect through rdp without an issue and, of course, I'm connected when this happens.

This server has a dedicated ip address, actually several of them. I pinged the primary dns ip 20 times and 2 of them had issues:

```
Pinging xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125

Ping statistics for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms



Pinging xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I'm not sure where to go from here or how to prove if it is the dedicated server company's issue or my server.

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.

** Edit #1 **

To add to the list, I tried to synchronize Evernote and this was in the log:

11:28:23 [4676] 0% Connecting to www.evernote.com
11:28:23 [4676] 0% * loaded updateCount: 67660
11:28:35 [4676] 0% Can't send HTTP request, error: INTERNET_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting static dns servers and pointing to 8.8.8.8 It looks like what ever DNS server you are pointing at is unreliable.

Comment: The servers are the dns servers that the dedicated hosting company assigned. Should I contact them about it? Also, do I put both the primary and secondary as the 8.8.8.8?

Comment: no. just the primary. test it for a bit, see if you get better stability. If you do, the hosting company is having serious issues with their dns servers and you probably should contact them (act of good faith).

Comment: that's a great starting point, thank you for the help!